# XML to custom Object

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have one xml file and I want to generate custom list from that xml using Linq.
here is my code. But I am not getting any records.Here is my code.

```
public class TemplateSettings {
        public string DecimalSeparator { get; set; }
        public string ThousandSeparator { get; set; }
        public string DateSeparator { get; set; }
        public string TimeSeparator { get; set; }
    }
```

XML Here

```
<TemplateSetting>
  <DecimalSeparator>1</DecimalSeparator> 
  <ThousandSeparator>2</ThousandSeparator> 
  <DateSeparator>3</DateSeparator> 
  <TimeSeparator>4</TimeSeparator> 
  <DateFormat>dd/MM/yyyy</DateFormat> 
  <ValueDelimiter>tr</ValueDelimiter> 
  <QuoteCharacter>r</QuoteCharacter> 
  <IsHeader>False</IsHeader> 
  </TemplateSetting>
```

And my code to get object from xml is

```
 var a = (from x in objTemplateMasterEAL.TemplatSettingsXML.Elements("TemplateSetting")
  select new TemplateSettings()
   {
      DateFormat = (string)x.Element("DateFormat"),
      DecimalSeparator = (string)x.Element("DecimalSeparator"),
      ThousandSeparator = (string)x.Element("ThousandSeparator"),
      DateSeparator = (string)x.Element("DateSeparator"),
      TimeSeparator = (string)x.Element("TimeSeparator"),
      QuoteCharacter = (string)x.Element("QuoteCharacter"),
      ValueDelimiter = (string)x.Element("ValueDelimiter"),
      IsHeaderLine = (bool)x.Element("IsHeader")
  }).ToList<TemplateSettings>();
```

Can any one suggest me what is wrong here ?

Comment: what is happening currently? any errors?

Comment: I am getting 0 record.

Comment: Why not use the XML Schema tool to make things easier? You can create .Net classes from an .xsd, and then when you have an .Xml file which adheres to the .Xsd, you can create an object of the generated type without having to manually select the data.

Comment: Is that the full class definition that you've posted?

Comment: Is it possible for you to post any link ?

Comment: no I think I missed 3 fields ( QuoteCharacter ,ValueDelimiter ,IsHeaderLine  ).

Comment: What is `TemplatSettingsXML` and how are you setting it?

Comment: Currently I am getting xml from database column.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is just to deserialize the XML to object you can simply use this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("Sample.xml"))
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TemplateSetting));
            var templateSetting = (TemplateSetting)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }

    }
}

[XmlRoot]
public class TemplateSetting
{
    public string DecimalSeparator { get; set; }
    public string ThousandSeparator { get; set; }
    public string DateSeparator { get; set; }
    public string TimeSeparator { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I make only on one change and its working fine for me.

```
<TemplateSettings>
<TemplateSetting>
  <DecimalSeparator>1</DecimalSeparator> 
  <ThousandSeparator>2</ThousandSeparator> 
  <DateSeparator>3</DateSeparator> 
  <TimeSeparator>4</TimeSeparator> 
  <DateFormat>dd/MM/yyyy</DateFormat> 
  <ValueDelimiter>tr</ValueDelimiter> 
  <QuoteCharacter>r</QuoteCharacter> 
  <IsHeader>False</IsHeader> 
  </TemplateSetting>
</TemplateSettings>
```